# Why would Android 2.2 reboot after install of an .apk file?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I am getting reports from beta testers that after installing my .apk file their device is rebooting. After reboot the application operates as normal. Reboot after installation is not part of the desired/expected behavior, and itself sounds like a security breach.

Can anyone speculate as to why Android might reboot after an .apk install?

UPDATE:

One of the devices was an LG Ally, the other was a Samsung Galaxy Note

Comment: i would get the models of those devices and see whats different.  just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Are your Beta users using a rooted device? Do they have some kind of security app like "Lookout" installed on their device?

I'd suggest that you make your app [create a trace log](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#creatingtracefiles) on the sdcard, that you'd get your beta tester to email to you.

Of course, this debugging process would be easier if someone loaned you the same model of the device your beta user is using.

Comment: The user has rooted his device and is running "SuperUser", but not Lookout. How might that cause a reboot?

Comment: Rooting and SuperUser by themselves won't do anything. It's just that if the device is rooted, they may have installed a security application with root privileges, or they may have installed a custom rom that redoes the deodexing of an apk on the fly (I think I've seen at least one custom ROM that tried to do something like that). And as to Lookout, my understanding it that checks an apk before and after an install, and that it uses so many undocumented hacks that it can cause trouble on its own (even if it technically doesn't have root privileges).

Comment: And actually, I was only grasping at straws. Trying to guess this early-on in the process of debugging is counter-productive. There could be 101 possible reasons this symptom is showing up with your Beta users, and I've only listed 2 possible reasons so far. I don't think you can guess your way out of this one, you really do need to get yourself some trace logs of what happens just before the phone reboots itself, and then formulate your theories based on those logs.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what your app should never be able to crash the operating system.  A lot of this can depend on the device and manufacturer.  For example, I noticed that when using a certain app to stream music on 2.3.x on the Droid X, the device would sometimes restart.  I could not fix this issue myself but instead had to wait until a fix was provided by Motorola (which it eventually was).  I would see if you can find a common occurrence on certain devices or manufacturers then do some researching on their reported bugs page.  Also, what type of application is this (game/media/utility?)

Comment: I updated the device type in my question; no commonality with Device, though my headline may be inaccurate as I believe the Galaxy Note is Android 2.3 not 2.2 like the Ally. The app is a social networking app.